# Speed of summation over a boolean array

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, sum, boolean

suppose I want to sum over an array of booleans:

```
bool arrray[LARGE_SIZE];
```

which one of the following code has more speed?

```
int sum=0;
for(int i=0;i<LARGE_SIZE)
   if(array[i]) sum++;
```

and

```
int sum=0;
for(int i=0;i<LARGE_SIZE)
   sum+=array[i] ;
```

Is there any other way to speed up?
these codes are used in a loop and even small speed difference is important.

Comment: Most probably the `if` version will be slower because of branch predictor kicking in, but seriously, if it matters, just measure.

Comment: I tested it and it seems that if version has more speed , but why?

Comment: @abdolahS: there's no point asking such a question when we don't know whether the difference you observed is statistically significant, repeatable, unrelated to other processing your computer's doing at the time, whether you've enabled optimisation, the assembly language or machine code your compiler's produced, what CPU you're running on etc...  Separately, consider using [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) and [`.count()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/count), or - generally - keeping track of the number of "on" bits as they're (re)set.

Comment: Yes, the OP didn't really show much research effort, but downvoting it seems a bit harsh.

Comment: @TonyD You should make that (*Separately, consider using `std::bitset` and `.count()`*) into an answer.

Comment: @Walter: well - there may be e.g. C or library compatibility reasons it can't be done in this case, but feel free to post it as such if you like.

Comment: @Walter: That's precisely what downvoting indicates. It's not "harsh" or something to be taken personally. It's an objective value judgement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always **MEASURE**. Only measurement can tell you how the code behaves in a given context (given compiler and options, given machine, given load etc.). Still, the code without a choice has a better chance of performing well, if the choice is not optimized away by the compiler.

---

If the speed really mattered I would also try out `std::accumulate`, because it might just be optimized for the task at hand.

---

And as [Tony D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410767/tony-d) implicitly points out in a [comment to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538538/speed-of-summation-over-a-boolean-array#comment45391644_28538538), the choice of algorithm and data structure generally has more influence on the speed than micro-scale optimizations. For example, by updating a count for every operation that changes a value, inspection of the count can be constant time. Unfortunately, as far as I can determine, neither `std::bitset` (for an array of size known at compile time) nor `boost::dynamic_bitset` (for a dynamic size array) guarantee this behavior.